# Combinatorics question, combinations involved in filling up of vacancies.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> To fill $12$ vacancies, there are $25$ candidates of which $5$ are from
>   scheduled castes. If $3$ vacancies are reserved for scheduled caste
>   candidates while the rest are open to all, find the number of ways in
>   which selections can be made?

According to me it should be $^5C_3×^{22}C_9$ because we first find the combinations for scheduled castes then multiply it with the combinations for *all the remaining candidates* (including the scheduled castes).

However, answer given is $10 \times ^{20}C_9+ 5 \times ^{20}C_8 + ^{20}C_ 7$.

Why is my reasoning incorrect?

**Edit**: I have realised my error, now how do I eliminate it and get the right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasoning is incorrect because you're counting multiple times. Let's focus *only* on the "scheduled caste" section at the moment. Call the "scheduled caste" members A, B, C, D, E. These two cases are the same:

- A, B, C make it through reservation and D, E make it through an open slot; rest same
- A, D, E make it through reservation and B, C make it through an open slot; rest same

You have considered them as distinct.

This would be clearer with a simpler problem: if you would get rid of all non-"scheduled" members make a selection of five from the "scheduled" group, with three reserved and two open. There is in effect only one way to do so, but with your method it is 5C3 * 2C2.

EDIT: To eliminate OP's error, just notice the simple fact that the number of people making it is $3$, $4$ or $5$ from the "scheduled" community. If we separated the entry process into the two classes reserved and non-reserved, we'd be counting multiple times because it doesn't matter what process a "scheduled" person is selected by as long as the selections are the same. Instead, we separate people into classes scheduled and non-scheduled. There are three cases: 3 from "scheduled", rest from open *only*; 4 from "scheduled", rest from open *only* and 5 from "scheduled", rest from open *only*.

So  we simply calculate $\binom{5}3 \cdot \binom{20}{9} + \binom{5}4 \cdot \binom{20}8 + \binom{5}5 \cdot \binom{20}7$ and we're done.

Comment: How do I eliminate my error?

Comment: Editing it right away.

Comment: Please Check the answer from this book.  This is the correct answer.  The OP has answered it correctly in the first place http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/keep207.pdf See answer to the question 59 in page number 127

Answer (score -1):

There are more candidates than vacancies.  The way the answer is structured is that possible ways the selection could be made is to fill the 3 vacancies from 5 SC, and the remaining 9 from Non-SC, 4 SC are placed and the remaining 8 from Non_SC and all 5 Scs are placed and the remaining 7 from Non-SC.  I would kind of agree with you that the 3 vacancies are filled from 5 SCs and the remaining nine vacancies are filled with 22 open candidates.  In the textbook solution, it assumes that all 5 SC candidates are placed which is not mentioned in the problem.